# Cannot stick header on top of the page

Tags: html, css, header

I have a header that I want to scroll up/down along with the page.That works.  I also want to "stick" it to the top of the page.

I keep getting this gap between the header and the top of the page. Check the image. How can I close this gap?

This is the `css` of the header

```
header {

    padding-left:5%;
    padding-right:5%;
    margin:auto;
        margin-top:0%;
        padding-top:0%;
        top:0;
    width: 50%;
        height:auto;
    border-left:1px solid gray;
    border-right:1px solid gray;
    border-top:1px solid gray;
    border-bottom:1px solid gray;
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
    background-color:#5C8AE6;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom:0%;
    overflow:auto;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 10px 10px #C9C9C9;
    -webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 10px 10px #C9C9C9;
    -moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 10px 10px #C9C9C9;

  /* Shadow around the header, For IE<9 */  
  filter:
 progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#C9C9C9, direction=0, strength=5),  

progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#C9C9C9, direction=45, strength=2),  

progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#C9C9C9, direction=90, strength=5),  

progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#C9C9C9, direction=135, strength=5),  

progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#C9C9C9, direction=180, strength=10),  

progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#C9C9C9, direction=225, strength=5),  

progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#C9C9C9, direction=270, strength=5),  

progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#C9C9C9, direction=315, strength=2);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#5C8AE6, #6C96E8);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#5C8AE6, #6C96E8);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#5C8AE6, #6C96E8);
    background: linear-gradient(#5C8AE6, #6C96E8);
}][1]
```

What am I missing ?

Thanks

[image: header example]

Comment: Or a link to the page. It could be something else in your HTML or CSS causing the issue. Also, which browser has the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have     `top:0;` but you have no position assigned

Use

`position: absolute;`  if you want the header to scroll with the rest of the page

use

`position: fixed;` if you want the header to stick to the top, and have the content scroll past it.

Answer (score 1):

For the Fixed header - You need to add `position:fixed;` css attribute

Add, if you want to remove the spaces, Add below properties to `header`

```
position:absolute;
margin-top:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: fixed;` and `left: 20%;` to keep your `header` center.

[JSFiddle demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Tn6u6/)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with:

```
 position: absolute;
```

I would also use for the border radius the webkit and moz components to ensure cross-browser compatibility.

```
-webkit-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
```

I would also set the margin avoiding percentage, even if it probably have no impact

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: [No need to add `-webkit-` or `-moz-` to `border-radius` anymore](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius).

Comment: For that matter, he probably could remove those from `box-shadow` as well

Comment: And sadly I'm still having Clients (using Mac) that won't see the rounded border - nor shadow - if I don't add the webkit prefix.

Comment: That's surprising -- but you gotta do what you gotta do I suppose. From what I can tell, the last few versions of OSX ship with Safari > 4.0 (so not needed), and with standard OS updates, you get border-radius support as far back as OSX 10.5 "Leopard" (released in '07).